# Count Child Menu From Same Table On Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, count

I have mysql table like below, I have tried to count child from parent menu in same table, but I am very confused to do it. I am still a beginner in mysql, how to solve it?

```
menuId     | menuName  | menuType  | menuParentId  
-------------------------------------------------
1          | Settings  | parent    | NULL          
2          | Set1      | child     | 1             
3          | Set2      | child     | 1             
4          | Category  | parent    | NULL         
5          | Cat1      | child     | 4             
6          | Cat2      | child     | 4             
7          | Dashboard | parent    | NULL
```

My Expectation Result Like This:

```
menuId     | menuName  | countChild | open 
--------------------------------------------
1          | Settings  | 2          | true           
2          | Set1      | 0          | false                            
3          | Set2      | 0          | false                            
4          | Category  | 2          | true                       
5          | Cat1      | 0          | false                            
6          | Cat2      | 0          | false                           
7          | Dashboard | 0          | false
```

Thanks For Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a self left join to count children for each menu, For `open` use `case` statement over result of aggregate function `COUNT`

```
SELECT a.menuId,
       a.menuName,
       COUNT(b.menuId) countChild,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(b.menuId) > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END `open`
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.menuId = b.menuParentId
GROUP BY a.menuId, a.menuName
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fa215/1)

If you want to show true and false as string put them in [qoutes](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fa215/2)

Comment: Wow, nice answer brother, thanks a lot... wassalamu Alaikum

Comment: Why don't you just use `COUNT(b.menuId) > 0 AS \`open\``. Since `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`, the result would always be the same.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes you are right , this would be a shorthand check